# segmentation fault with char*

Tags: c, character-encoding, char, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a function in c that receives a file name such as "file name. network number", for example:
matriz.0
This indicates that matrix is associated with a code, for example the number 1, and 0 is the network number. This means that I must generate a numeric code with the 1 and 0 and return an int.
The function, is well coded and it works if I use it separately in another program in c, but then adding it to the main program I have noticed that the char * string manipulation generates fault. Because if I comment the 3 lines in the function:

```
filename = strtok (string, ".");
red = strtok (NULL, ".");
codigored = atoi (red);
```

The segmentation fault disappears. I tried to allocate memory and initialize all variables but the error persists, so anyone can help find the error? thank you very much.

The following is the code of the function in c:

```
int generasubPalabra(char* nombre) 
{
   char *nombrearchivo=NULL; 
   int codigoarchivo=0;  
   char *red=NULL;                
   int codigored=0;                 

   int subpalabra=1;
   nombrearchivo = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*50);  //50 chars

   red = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*4); 

   char cadena[strlen(nombre)+1];

   strcpy(cadena, nombre);          



   //ACA ESTA EL ERROR: alguna de las 3 funciones, o las 3, genera una violacion de segmento
   //romper cadena en nombre - nro de red
   //Primera llamada => Primer token (primer elemento hasta el punto, es el nombre del archivo)  

   nombrearchivo = strtok( cadena, "." );       
   printf( "nombre del archivo %s\n", nombrearchivo );

 //Segunda llamada => Segundo token (segundo elemento, desde el punto, es el nro de red)
   red = strtok( NULL, "." );                   
   printf( "numero de red %s\n", red );

   codigored=atoi(red);                 //obtengo el entero correspodiente a la red (cast)
   printf( "codigo de red %d\n", codigored );

   //con la siguiente secuencia se traduce el string contenido en nombrearchivo, al codigo correspondiente para la palabra


   if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_incidencia")==0) {
       codigoarchivo=1;
   } 
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_brazos_inhibidores")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=2;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_prioridades_red")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=3;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_relacion_disparos_distribuidos")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=4;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_prioridades_disparos_distribuidos")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=5;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_marcado_inicial")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=6;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_cotas_plazas")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=7;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_transiciones_automaticas")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=8;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_transiciones_noinformadas")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=9;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_mascara_interrupciones")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=10;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_cola_entrada")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=11;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_consulta_disparo_especifico")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=12;
   }
   else if (strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_consulta_plaza")==0) {
        codigoarchivo=13;
   }
   else {
        codigoarchivo=31;  //se retorna el ultimo valor posible (5bits =11111)
        printf("No existe el archivo, verifique ubicacion y permisos \n");
   }

   printf( "codigo de archivo %d\n", codigoarchivo );   

   //se concatena en los 5 bits mas significativos la red, y en los siguientes 5 bits mas significativos el codigo de archivo

   subpalabra = 0x000;                      

   subpalabra+= 0x080*codigored;            //red

   subpalabra+= 0x004*codigoarchivo;        //codigo de archivo

   printf("la subpalabra generada es: %x\n", subpalabra);

return subpalabra;

}
```

Here is the complete code:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/q782v5cmrcdgl2b/matriz.c

to run, use the command

"./matriz path_where_are_the_matrices"
by example:
./matriz /home/eduardo/hpn/matrices

on that route, place a file with an array with the name:
matriz_brazos_inhibidores.1
 
file matrix example is as follows
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ur3ucbf8cdmfpmf/matriz_brazos_inhibidores.1

Comment: Please construct a **simple** test-case for us to look at.

Comment: `red = strtok (NULL, ".")` is probably the problem. have you check if the last call didn't return a `null` pointer? I also don't understand how this: `char cadena[strlen(nombre)+1]` can compile

Comment: oli:an example of execution is as follows
the file name to be manipulated is matriz.0

matrix is associated with the code: 1
the network has associated the code 0

the sub-word to be generated must be of the form:
Network code: 5 most significant bits = 0
filename code: following 5 bits = 1
the remaining 2 bits of the integer must be 0
ie that the code generated is = 0x004 (00000 (red) 00001 (code file) 00

Comment: taylor: I tested if it returns a null pointer and does not, at this time I am dealing with one single file name, and returns a valid code.

char string [strlen (name) +1]: This line creates a string that is the size of "name" +1, to manipulate it:
 nombrearchivo = strtok( cadena, "." );    

add this to test if the variable name was not that I was causing the problem in this line

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you have absolutely no error checking. Read up on the functions you're using so that you can tell if they're returning successfully or not. Also, you're usage of memory is completely backwards. Malloc is mainly used when you don't know the size of the memory ahead of time. You should be using it like this:

```
char nombrearchivo[50]; // instead of malloc (sizeof (char) * 50); 
char * cadena = malloc (strlen(nombre) + 1);
```

Your lack of error checking starts here: `red = strtok(NULL, ".")`.Check to make sure that the call is successful or not by doing this:

```
if (nombrearchivo){
    red = strtok (NULL, ".");
    codigored = atoi (red);
}
```

Another possible cause is `atoi`. Are you checking that `red` contains a null terminated string of *just* numbers?

Are you checking to make sure that `nombre` isn't null? Add this:

```
if (!nombre) return -1; /* Or just check that you aren't sending a null
                         * pointer in the calling function
                         */
```

I rewrote your function with some standard practices and I got no errors:

```
int generasubPalabra (char* nombre){

    if (!nombre) return -1;

    char    * nombrearchivo = 0,
            * red = 0,
            * cadena = malloc (strlen (nombre)); /* strlen could lead to
                                                  * a seg fault if it
                                                  * isn't null-terminated.
                                                  */

    int codigoarchivo  = 0,
            codigored  = 0,
            subpalabra = 1;


    if (!cadena) return -1;

    strcpy(cadena, nombre); /* A seg fault wouldn't happen here without 
                             * first happening above, at strlen
                             */

    nombrearchivo = strtok (cadena, ".");

    if (!nombrearchivo) return -1;

    printf ("nombre del archivo %s\n", nombrearchivo);

    red = strtok (0, ".");

    if (!red) return -1;

    printf ("numero de red %s\n", red);

    codigored = atoi (red);
    printf ("codigo de red %d\n", codigored);

         if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_incidencia"))            codigoarchivo = 1;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_brazos_inhibidores"))    codigoarchivo = 2;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_prioridades_red"))       codigoarchivo = 3;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_relacion_disparos_distribuidos"))        codigoarchivo = 4;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"matriz_prioridades_disparos_distribuidos"))     codigoarchivo = 5;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_marcado_inicial"))               codigoarchivo = 6;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_cotas_plazas"))                  codigoarchivo = 7;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_transiciones_automaticas"))      codigoarchivo = 8;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_transiciones_noinformadas"))     codigoarchivo = 9;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_mascara_interrupciones"))        codigoarchivo = 10;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_cola_entrada"))                  codigoarchivo = 11;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_consulta_disparo_especifico"))   codigoarchivo = 12;
    else if (!strcmp(nombrearchivo,"vector_consulta_plaza"))                codigoarchivo = 13;
    else {
            codigoarchivo = 31;  //se retorna el ultimo valor posible (5bits =11111)
            printf ("No existe el archivo, verifique ubicacion y permisos \n");
    }
    printf ("codigo de archivo %d\n", codigoarchivo);

    subpalabra  = 0x000;
    subpalabra += 0x080*codigored;            //red
    subpalabra += 0x004*codigoarchivo;        //codigo de archivo

    printf ("la subpalabra generada es: %x\n", subpalabra);

    return subpalabra;
}

int main (){

    int ret = generasubPalabra ("matriz_brazos_inhibidores.1");

    if (ret < 0)
            printf ("Error occured\n");
    else    printf ("Result = %d\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Update:

After getting the entire source of your program, I found a couple things that were producing the segmentation faults. To test the program, I did this:

- made a test directory with one file in it
- labeled the file testname.1
- added some random words to it

Here's some of the changes I did to get a clean run:

- I used the function I edited instead of the one that was already there (fixed one fault)
- I changed one of your `for` loops to `for ( j = 0; j < espacios; j++)`, by replacing `<=`

And at the end of that loop, I added this:

```
     /* other code went here */
     printf("el valor a ser escrito long int: %s\n", msg);
  }
  // strtok right here was causing another seg fault
  pch = strtok (NULL, "\n "); //esto es como un reset de pch
  if (!pch){ // your solution to this problem might be different
     fclose (pFile); // just as long as it's taken care of before
     return 0; // the next iteration of the loop
  }
```

This may not solve your program's problems entirely. I wasn't able to add the most meaningful solution because I don't really understand how all your code is put together (I don't understand Spanish that well). But, if you just add more error checking in your code, you'll be able to either fix the problem or at least exactly what's causing it. I saw that you did check for errors in some of the functions, but it's just not enough. You have to act like nothing is going to go as planned. Ask yourself this:

- What if there's a file name in the directory that doesn't have a `.` symbol?
- What happens if there's a file with no extension number? Like `filename.`
- What if the extension number of the file has letters? ie `filename.423d2`
- What if there isn't any new lines in the file?
- What if there isn't *anything* in the file?
- What happens if the directory that was input isn't there? Or, is mistyped?

Point being this: you have to assume your program is running with completely unpredictable input.

Comment: hi, nombrearchivo should be a char *, not a char [50], because the strtok returns a char *

Comment: `char [50]` is equivalent to `char *`, but I see your point. In that case, don't allocate memory there at all.

Comment: not execute the following line (do not enter there)
if (!nombre) return -1;

Comment: the call to the function is done with the following string

Name entering: matriz_brazos_inhibidores.1

 filename is: matriz_brazos_inhibidores

ie I'm calling the function correctly because the printf its  printing the "nombre" after the initialization of variables in the function

Comment: thank you taylor
As I said, testing this function in a file c only, works well.
when I add the entire project is when problems appear.
Is that the problem is in this function, because if I comment the call to generasubPalabra the program (of entire proyect) works well.

Also note that the problem is in the handling of char *, in the same way, commenting those lines and seeing that the program works correctly.

I tried your code in my project and still giving the same error on the same line

Comment: if it's still giving your errors, it's probably `atoi`. You need to show us what other errors your getting, and more code.

Comment: I uploaded the entire project and how to run it.

would be great if you help me, thank you very much taylor

keep in mind what I said above, the program without generasubPalabra function call works correctly

the project does is to open files in a folder, containing arrays
parses the name to get a code (which generates generasubPalabra function)
then begins to loop through the array, and generates the complete word with the data to be sent  (the element of the array) and subcode

Comment: I got your code to work, it just needs error checking. I'll post more info in a little bit

Comment: The line:
for (j=0, j<=spaces; j++) {// travel columns
And this also coded in my code.

The line:
pch = strtok (NULL, "\ n");
Take the next token of "buffer", because this has been divided into the "\n", according to this line (so to travel splits rows):
char * pch = strtok (buffer, "\n");

Adding:
  if (! pch) {
      fclose (pFile) 
      return 0;
The execution of the program only takes the first element of the array and ends execution. If null is being charged with, then there will be a long integer that element scanning pch found at the following iteration:
sscanf (pch,"%lu",&value);

Comment: With regard to questions about your concern for the files and their format, do not worry, the directory will contain only matrices files being sent, and will have specific format as the example of the matrix I uploaded. That is to adhere to the format so that there are no errors.

Comment: You've missed my point completely. I've given you my suggestion, take it or leave it.

Comment: solved:
the problem is in the handling of characters within the function that makes the call to the function of this post (generasubPalabra).

What I did in the first instance to resolve the problem is to call generasubPalabra from the principal, and not from the other function (cargaMatriz).

I was recommended by the faculty is always allocate memory to char * and define limits to char [], which as Taylor said, is not fixed but is defined by a precondition (the size of a variable that is used). Otherwise start to have problems on the stack (the values ​​of the variables can be overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

As Taylor Flores pointed out, you have some interesting memory allocations in there but as you mentioned you were messing around with that, I'll assume thats why.

Make sure that the last index of cadena is initialized. If it is not (f.e. no null terminating character in the nombre string), throw in a null character, or else strtok will try to access a void in memory.

Also, you will need to use malloc (as mentioned by Taylor as well) to dynamically allocate and free the memory on run time, not doing this can and often will lead to problems as well.

Comment: egari: how do I check if the last character string is valid?
which according to you tell me, should be \0

Comment: cadena[strlen(nombre)] (which is the last index) should be '\0'.<br> You could always initialize the entire char * block to '\0' to be safe, but cadena[strlen(nombre)] = '\0'; should be fine.

Comment: im doing:
char cadena[strlen(nombre)] = '\0';

and the compiler says it can not be initialized in this way:
matriz.c: 259:4: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Comment: @eduardosufan you should really just read a book on `C`. The syntax is suppose to be `cadena[strlen(nombre)] = 0;`, after you've given it space with `malloc`

Comment: Thanks, I still get the same error, I will continue experimenting with what you say, that does not reach the /0 at the end of "nombree"